# Static page using Tridion 2013 SP1 and SmartTarget 2014

Tags: 2013, smarttarget, fredhopper

I have configured SmartTarget 2014 and Fredhopper with Tridion 2013 SP1 and followed steps below to create a static page.

Created a PT and attached all the TBB(s). Also I have created a dynamic CT for promotion components and attached the required TBB(s).   After that I have created the promotion component.

Next I have created promotion by going to Targeting Tab of CME Using Trigger as current date.

Finally I have created a page, but when browsing the page it is showing blank. Nothing is rendered onto the page.

Comment: Please edit your question to phrase it as a question.  Also provide your page code and error logs.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a page template with the .html extension? This won't be executed by your app server, and therefore the dynamic code won't run - either use .aspx or .jsp, or configure your app server to execute .html pages.

Comment: Yes page extension was html but after changing it to aspx its still the same

Comment: <smarttarget:Query AllowDuplicates="true" Publication="tcm:0-1048-1" runat="server">
<smarttarget:Promotions MaxItems="10" Region="Sidebar" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<smarttarget:PromotionalItems runat="server">           
</ItemTemplate> 
<tridion:ComponentPresentation runat="server" PageURI="tcm:1048-7183-64" ComponentURI="<%# Eval(&quot;ComponentUri&quot;) %>" TemplateURI="<%# Eval(&quot;TemplateUri&quot;) %>"/>          
</ItemTemplate>          
</smarttarget:PromotionalItems>     
</ItemTemplate><FallbackContent></FallbackContent> </smarttarget:Promotions></smarttarget:Query>

Comment: view source of the page

Comment: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_SmartTarget_2014-v1&lang=en-US#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-FC2C3E5F-0FBA-4E08-A112-F491B09F8E1D.xml&docid=GUID-FC2C3E5F-0FBA-4E08-A112-F491B09F8E1D&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-FC2C3E5F-0FBA-4E08-A112-F491B09F8E1D

Comment: If that's your source in the browser, then your app server is not configured to execute the tags... if you see that in File System then it seems correct.

Comment: Could you please let me know the steps/way out to execute or render the page in browser

Comment: Not sure I understand this question... Open a browser, type the URL, see what happens? If this is about configuring the App server to execute the tags, then it seems like you're using .NET (by the "runat=server" in your text): follow these steps: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_SmartTarget_2014_SP1-v1/GUID-8DC15425-9B9E-4AA1-B512-46F3CB4108C1